# Closing 2 JFrame instead of one

Tags: java

I've created a JFrame1 in which I've put a button to go to another JFrame2 
But when I close JFrame2 both of the frames close.
I only need JFrame2 to close.
How can I do that?

Comment: how are you closing the `JFrame`? are you using `System.exit()`?

Comment: I'm using mouse click

Comment: Sorry, are closing the frame by clicking on cross icon?

Comment: Yes I am clicking the cross icon

Comment: Change `myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` to, `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. But you're far better off not pushing a bunch of JFrames at the user. Better to swap views with a CardLayout, or use one JFrame and occasional modal JDialog when needed.

Comment: Please have a look at [JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: It says **When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate.**

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.
Will do. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your frame is setup to dispose on close not exit on close

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `frame.dispose()` if you are using a button to close the JFrame
- Use `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` if you want the X button on the menu bar to close the selected JFrame